# Convert to time format with leading zeros

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add a leading zero to all my cells if there is only a single digit in the hour place.

Example:
1AM to 01AM
9AM to 09AM
8:30AM to 08:30AM

But no change needed to 12AM

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Look into custom formats.

Comment: Do your cells contain times?  Or text?  (If times, probably see Mark's comment about custom formats, although I'm not sure whether you can easily suppress the minutes portion when it is zero.)

Answer (score 2):

Number format the cell so that it contains *hh* instead of *h*:

01AM → format = hhAM/PM

08:30AM → format = hh:mmAM/PM

This will have no impact on double-digit numbers (so no 0 added to them).